# Symfony2 collection and related choice field not (yet) managed

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I've got a form with a collection field "options" and a choice field "defaultOption". My goal is to enable the user to create a new entity, add some options and select a default option from the list of option he/she just added before saving the entire thing.

Here's part of the form that shows both fields:

```
            $form->add('options', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new CustomFieldOptionType(),
                'label' => 'custom.field.options',
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'options' => array(
                    'label_render' => false,
                    'widget_control_group' => false,
                ),
                'by_reference' => false,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'options')
            ));

            $form->add('defaultOption', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'custom.field.default',
                'class' => 'XFDOBundle:CustomFieldOption',
                'choices' => $field->getOptions(),
                'property' => 'name',
                'required' => false,
                'empty_value' => 'custom.field.default.empty',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'default-option')
            ));
```

I've tried several things with jquery and form event listeners to (re)populate the "defaultOption" field with the new (not-yet-persisted) options, but that resulted in to nothing or "Entities passed to the choice field must be managed" exceptions.

Any idea how I can get this working?

Comment: Does this functionality have to work on 1 for or could you use a 2 step process?

Comment: Sure, it's no problem to have an extra POST to resolve the new options available for the defaultOption field. What I would do in that case is post the entire form using ajax, bypass validation and replace the html for the defaultOption field like explained in the last part of this [Symfony article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms)
The ajax post would then be invoked whenever a new option get's added by the user.